# Adding IPNS link to ipfs-desktop

Tags: distributed, ipfs, decentralized-applications

What is the correct way to add an IPNS site to ipfs-desktop?
The purpose would be to seed a website on several computers, let's say 5.
So, I give my IPNS link to 5 of my friends. How can they contribute to hosting that site?

Comment: Currently I don't think there's a built-in way to do it. You could use a cronjob, and check if the ipns address has updated via `ipfs name resolve <ipnsAddr>`, then update a pin via `ipfs pin update <oldCID> <newCID>`.

Comment: Yes, now I'm doing `ipfs pin add -r /ipns/<ipnsAddr>`, but cronjob is necessary.
Pinning the IPNS address itself will keep the old versions as well, I didn't know about pin update.

Comment: This is how I'm currently doing it https://github.com/imestin/ipfs-blog-daemon/tree/master/bash

Comment: That's exactly how I'd do it currently (I'm hoping a feature like IPNS pinning will be available in the future), `ipfs pin update` is really useful as it'll automatically unpin the old blocks.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/issues/4435